# logstash output to elasticsearch index and mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm trying to have logstash output to elasticsearch but I'm not sure how to use the mapping I defined in elasticsearch...

In Kibana, I did this:

Created an index and mapping like this:

```
PUT /kafkajmx2
{
  "mappings": {
    "kafka_mbeans": {
      "properties": {
        "@timestamp": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "@version": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "host": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "metric_path": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "type": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "path": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "metric_value_string": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "metric_value_number": {
          "type": "float"
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Can write data to it like this:

```
POST /kafkajmx2/kafka_mbeans
{
  "metric_value_number":159.03478490788203,
  "path":"/home/usrxxx/logstash-5.2.0/bin/jmxconf",
  "@timestamp":"2017-02-12T23:08:40.934Z",
  "@version":"1","host":"localhost",
  "metric_path":"node1.kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=TotalFetchRequestsPerSec.FifteenMinuteRate",
  "type":null


}
```

now my logstash output looks like this:

```
input {
        kafka {
                kafka details here
        }

}
output {

    elasticsearch {
            hosts => "http://elasticsearch:9050"
            index => "kafkajmx2"

    }

}
```

and it just writes it to the `kafkajmx2` index but doesn't use the map, when I query it like this in kibana:

```
get /kafkajmx2/kafka_mbeans/_search?q=*
{


}
```

I get this back:

```
      {
        "_index": "kafkajmx2",
        "_type": "logs",
        "_id": "AVo34xF_j-lM6k7wBavd",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "@timestamp": "2017-02-13T14:31:53.337Z",
          "@version": "1",
          "message": """
{"metric_value_number":0,"path":"/home/usrxxx/logstash-5.2.0/bin/jmxconf","@timestamp":"2017-02-13T14:31:52.654Z","@version":"1","host":"localhost","metric_path":"node1.kafka.server:type=SessionExpireListener,name=ZooKeeperAuthFailuresPerSec.Count","type":null}

"""
        }
      }
```

how do I tell it to use the map `kafka_mbeans` in the logstash output?

-----EDIT-----

I tried my output like this but still get the same results:

```
output {

        elasticsearch {
                hosts => "http://10.204.93.209:9050"
                index => "kafkajmx2"
                template_name => "kafka_mbeans"
                codec => plain {
                        format => "%{message}"
                }

        }

}
```

the data in elastic search should look like this:

```
{
  "@timestamp": "2017-02-13T14:31:52.654Z", 
  "@version": "1", 
  "host": "localhost", 
  "metric_path": "node1.kafka.server:type=SessionExpireListener,name=ZooKeeperAuthFailuresPerSec.Count", 
  "metric_value_number": 0, 
  "path": "/home/usrxxx/logstash-5.2.0/bin/jmxconf", 
  "type": null
}
```

--------EDIT 2--------------

I atleast got the message to parse into json by adding a filter like this:

```
input {
        kafka {
                ...kafka details....
        }

}
filter {
        json {
                source => "message"
                remove_field => ["message"]
        }
}
output {

        elasticsearch {
                hosts => "http://node1:9050"
                index => "kafkajmx2"
                template_name => "kafka_mbeans"
        }

}
```

It doesn't use the template still but this atleast parses the json correctly...so now I get this:

```
  {
    "_index": "kafkajmx2",
    "_type": "logs",
    "_id": "AVo4a2Hzj-lM6k7wBcMS",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "metric_value_number": 0.9967205071482902,
      "path": "/home/usrxxx/logstash-5.2.0/bin/jmxconf",
      "@timestamp": "2017-02-13T16:54:16.701Z",
      "@version": "1",
      "host": "localhost",
      "metric_path": "kafka1.kafka.network:type=SocketServer,name=NetworkProcessorAvgIdlePercent.Value",
      "type": null
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you need to change is very simple. First use the `json` codec in your `kafka` input. No need for the `json` filter, you can remove it.

```
    kafka {
            ...kafka details....
            codec => "json"
    }
```

Then in your `elasticsearch` output you're missing the mapping type (parameter `document_type` below), which is important otherwise it defaults to `logs` (as you can see) and that doesn't match your `kafka_mbeans` mapping type. Moreover, you don't really need to use template since your index already exists. Make the following modification:

```
    elasticsearch {
            hosts => "http://node1:9050"
            index => "kafkajmx2"
            document_type => "kafka_mbeans"
    }
```

Comment: Sad that you didn't provide any feedback on whether it solved your issue

Comment: so sorry about the late extremely late response...I had to unplug from this for a while but that did work!

Answer (score -1):

This is defined with [the `template_name` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-template_name) on the `elasticsearch` output.

```
elasticsearch {
        hosts         => "http://elasticsearch:9050"
        index         => "kafkajmx2"
        template_name => "kafka_mbeans"
}
```

One warning, though. If you want to start creating indexes that are boxed on time, such as one index a week, you will have to take a few more steps to ensure your mapping stays with each. You have a couple of options there:

- Create an elasticsearch template, and define it to apply to indexes using a glob. Such as `kafkajmx2-*`
- Use [the `template` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-template) on the output, which specifies a JSON file that defines your mapping that will be used with all indexes created through that output.

Comment: so I tried to add that but when I do this in Kibana...`GET kafkajmx2/kafka_mbeans/_search?q=* {}` I get nothing back....everything is sitll going into `kafkajmx2` still like in the question...

Comment: @user2061886 You will need `type => "kafka_mbeans"` on your input. A logstash `type` is equivalent to what you're calling a `mapping`.

Comment: @user2061886 Ah, I'm still on 2.2.

Comment: sorry...missread your comment....I tried to put `type => "kafka_mbeans"` in the input but still when I do `get /kafkajmx2/kafka_mbeans/_search?q=* {}` I get no results....doing a `get /kafkajmx2/_search?q=* {} ` returns data though...

Comment: `template_name` did not work where as `document_type` did as noted in the other answer